# Aptana "Building Workspace" extremely slow

Tags: javascript, aptana

I'm running a pretty big web application (around 1.5gb) on my local server and I just added the project into Aptana. It automatically started building the work space after being added and started slowing down drastically whenever it encounters a Javascript file.

What exactly does building the workspace even do? Is there a way to shut it off if it's not much use? It's been stuck at 24% scanning different .js files for over 15 minutes now.

Comment: Answered for a great deal here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505229/disable-building-workspace-process-in-eclipse

Answer (score 21):

I have the same problem here. If I want to save my files and the 'Build Project' Operation is active, Aptana 3 stucks and I need to wait until the 'Build Project' Operation is done.

The 'Build Project' Operation means that the dependencies would be updated and the autocomplete function (over more then one file) can work with the newest changes. 
For example: if u add a new html tag with a id="test", the autocomplete feature would show you this id in any corresponding css file if the wokspace was rebuild.

To turn of this function, visit the preferences (Aptana Studio 3, build: **3.3.1.201212171919**): General -> Workspace -> 'Build Atomatically' Checkbox

**Update:**

To turn of this function, visit the preferences (Aptana Studio 3, build: **3.4.1.201306062137**): Project > 'Build Automatically' Checkbox

I hope they will increase the performance for this feature!

Have fun :)

Comment: For Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.1.201306062137 this functionality has moved to `Project > Build Automatically`