# Java Eclipse turn off auto build workspace on save

Tags: eclipse, build, save, workspace

Suddenly my Eclipse have started to automatically build the workspace whenever I save and it take ages for just a single save (I tend to save very often). It has never done that before so I was wondering: how do I to turn it off?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable building workspace process in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505229/disable-building-workspace-process-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you want to turn off auto Building your project, click the **Project** menu and uncheck the **Build automatically** menu.
[image]

Comment: Also available in the Workspace settings: Windows –> Preferences –> General –> workspace --> uncheck "Build Automatically" box. Source, including screenshots: https://www.benchresources.net/how-to-build-java-project-in-eclipse-ide-automatically/.

Comment: Often this options is automatically unflagged eclipse... I cannot understand why