# How to stop Eclipse Auto Build on save comments

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I want to stop auto build only when i add somme comments, because it will not affect my code.
How can i tell eclipse IDE to not restart server after writing comments?

Comment: [Maybe you can turn off auto Building your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328183/java-eclipse-turn-off-auto-build-workspace-on-save)

Comment: The Project, Build automatically setting is all there is. It either rebuilds on every change, or not at all.

Comment: Adding comments may not change the final byte code, but it definitely can change the line mapping information used in stack traces and when debugging.