# Cron job to let Eclipse build workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, cron

When I start my Eclipse, it often takes a really long time to "build workspace".  Is there a way to create a cron job to let it build it at night when I'm not using the workspace?

Comment: While not a cron answer, did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505229/disable-building-workspace-process-in-eclipse? Do you have validators on any of the projects? Do you have open projects that may be closed?

Comment: For that matter, what happens when you let it just build Automatically (incrementally)? What, exactly, is it building?

Answer (score 0):

Disable Project --> Build Automatically first in Eclipse. Create Jar/War file quickly by installing and configuring Maven for your project.

If you want to execute it at night/latter then add a simple shell script in crontab to execute following  mvn command.

> **mvn clean package**